# How to access just the values in an Object.Entries() so React doesn't give me a warning?

Tags: reactjs, object

React gives me an error:

```
'key' is assigned a value but never used
```

But I don't need to use the keys ever, so how do I work around this?

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            if (value === 'null') {
                let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
                arr.push(random);
            } else {
                let newValue = parseInt(value);
                arr.push(newValue);
            }
        }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, discarding the first entry since it isn't used (note the comma):

```
for (const [, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code.

```
let user = {
name: "John",
age: 30
};
// loop over values
for (let value of Object.values(user)) {
  alert(value); // John, then 30
}
```